# How to create a RedHat repository with a reduced set of packages

Tags: repository, rhel7

Dears,

I am managing a pool of servers running under RHEL 7.6, I created a local repository of RHEL packages to be able to udpated the other servers by limiting the internet access to the server hosting the local repository.

I used the reposync command to populate my repository but I am downloading a huge number of rpms packages!

I would like to reduce the set of packages to download to the ones already deployed on all the severs, I can do the list using the rpm command, (~750 packages).

- I read that there is an includepkgs directive to be used with the reposync command.
  How is it working, what is the required format?
- I know it is possible to use the yumdownloader command to update the local repository, how is it possible to populate the repository for the first time ?

Any help advice would be appreciated

Regards
Fdv

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best option is to limit to the last version of the packages by using the option :

```
-n, --newest-only     Download only newest packages per-repo
```